# Syntaxt for Writing a mySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to write a query which

UPDATE ALL

SET new values=x

WHERE old_values=y AND entity_id IS NOT 615, 611 or 606

So, I know I start with

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` 
SET `attribute_set_id`=[10],`type_id`=[configurable] 
WHERE `attribute_set_id`=[4],`type_id`=[simple]
```

however I don't know how to do it where entity_id IS NOT ?

Thanks

Henry

Answer (score 2):

In your where clause use `AND` to separate your criteria.

The `Not in` will allow you to exclude entities

```
UPDATE `catalog_product_entity` 
SET `attribute_set_id`=[10],`type_id`=[configurable] 
WHERE `attribute_set_id`=[4] 
AND `type_id`=[simple]
AND entity_id not in (615,611,606)
```

Comment: will give this a whirl this evening. didn't know it was `not in` that I had to use

Comment: Modified it a tad but got it working.. Unfortunately, i don't know what the differences were, however I will have to do it again soon, so will past back the code I used...

Thanks

Henry

Comment: Glad you got it working, I'll be interested in your reply.  If I can add anything so that this can be more clear and marked as answer, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with a list

```
and entity_id not in (615,611,606)
```

Equally valid, but harder is with or logic

```
and 
(
entity_id <> 615
or entity_id <> 611
or entity_id <> 606
)
```